# StreamBuilder doesn't rebuild after stream changed by setState

Tags: flutter

I have a StatefulWidget in which, there is a variable called stream that is initialized to an initial stream:

```
var stream = stream1;
```

When setState is called:

```
setState(() {
 condition ? stream = stream1 : stream = stream2;
});
```

These streams are consumed by a StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
 stream: stream,
 builder: (context, snap) {
  return RaisedButton(
   child: ..
   onPressed: snap.hasData ? () => my_function() : null
  );
 }
)
```

The problem is that when the builder function gets the data by the stream and the button becomes clickable and then the state changes, the new StreamBuilder button remains clickable though the second stream doesn't have data. In fact if a click the button my_function() isn't being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually not that `StreamBuilder` doesn't rebuild, but that it preserves the last emitted event.

As such, you cannot simply check `snapshot.hasData`. You will have to check `snapshot.connectionState` too.

When `StreamBuilder` receives a new stream, `snapshot.connectionState` will reset to `ConnectionState.waiting` until at least one value is emmited.

So instead of:

```dart
onPressed: snap.hasData ? () => my_function() : null
```

you can do:

```dart
onPressed: snap.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting && snap.hasData ? () => my_function() : null
```